# How does USB C PD to DC power negotiation work

Tags: power, dc, protocol

I have a battery and would like it to output power from its USBC PD to a DC input device. The device has a fixed resistance and the device must receive 20V fixed. How can I do this?

Comment: google `How does USB C PD to DC power negotiation work`

Answer (score 0):

You should really follow jsotola's advice and investigate further the spec.

As far as application specific stuff, I will point out that you will need to isolate the bus from your load until the negotiation succeeds. If you fail to do so, you will interfere with the source device's ability to establish 5V safe to do the contract handshakes and you will never get a successful contract.

The way we typically do this in industry is we have the sink device's micro turn on a high side PFET to allow current into the load (whatever it happens to be). *If and only if* the correct contract comes through (in this case 20V).